# Does the Elegoo Mars printer support additional file formats?

Tags: file-formats, elegoo-mars

I recently bought an [Elegoo Mars 3D printer](https://www.elegoo.com/product/elegoo-mars-uv-photocuring-lcd-3d-printer/).  Generally speaking, I'm quite happy with it. But, I don't care for the slicing software, Chitubox.  Does the Elegoo Mars support other 3D file formats?  I have tried *.stl files, but they don't seem to work with the factory firmware.

Comment: Stl files are source models, not the sliced data for the printer. I'm not familiar with resin printer file formats. What does their proprietary slicer output?

Comment: A Chitubox file, with a *.cbddlp extension.

Comment: Searching for it turns up that it's the same thing as .photon format and there are a number of open source tools for working with it. I would start with googling "photon slicer" and see what you find in the results.

Answer (score 2):

It also works with the `.photon` format of the Photon slicer.

It is only marginally better than ChituBox though.